# Telerik RadButton with ContentTemplate not showing radio button

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I've created two radio buttons with the following code:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbOption1" runat="server" Text="option 1" ToggleType="Radio"
    GroupName="group1" ButtonType="ToggleButton" />
<br />
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbOption2" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio"
    GroupName="group1" ButtonType="ToggleButton">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblChoose" runat="server" Text="choose" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoose" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

I want the second radbutton to be rendered with a radio button just the the first radbutton. But instead the entire contents of the content template is being rendered as an html anchor and no radio button is being shown for the second radbutton. Is there a way to use the telerik radbutton to look like this mockup?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the content of a RadButton is specified through the **ContentTemplate** inner property, the button control is automatically configured in a **LinkButton** mode.

The desired functionality can be achieved via two RadButtons, configured as radio buttons (ToggleType="Radio" ButtonType="ToggleButton"), and a DropDownList control that can be enabled only when one of the radio buttons is checked:

Page

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbOption1" runat="server" Text="option 1" ToggleType="Radio"
    GroupName="group1" ButtonType="ToggleButton" />
<br />
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbOption2" runat="server" Text="choose" ToggleType="Radio"
    GroupName="group1" ButtonType="ToggleButton" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoose" runat="server" Enabled="false">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Text" Value="Value"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Text" Value="Value"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlChoose.Enabled = rbOption2.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks for your help.